# Convert more than one char to an int in a string in Java

Tags: java, unicode, char, int

I understand how to convert a single `char` to an `int`, but how can I convert a `String` to `char`s, so I can convert the `char`s to `int`s? For example, for the string `hello`:

```
chars[1] = h => 104
chars[2] = e => 101
chars[3] = l => 108
chars[4] = l => 108
chars[5] = o => 111
```

The output should make it easy to convert five-letter `String`s to five separate integers, each representing one character, then convert them back to `char` and print them as a single `String` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
String s = "hello";
char[] data = s.toCharArray(); // returns a length 5 char array ( 'h','e','l','l','o' )
```

Now you can call this function to convert it into int.

```
int charToInt(char []data,int start,int end) throws NumberFormatException
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        int digit = (int)data[i] - (int)'0';
        if ((digit < 0) || (digit > 9)) throw new NumberFormatException();
        result *= 10;
        result += digit;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how that function works so it's not just blind copypasta? And maybe format it to match the Java MoS? (i.e. brackets on the same line as the related statements, `char []data` to `char[] data`, spaces after commas, etc.)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes The idea is to first create a `char[]` full of the letters in the `String`. Then, one by one, convert them to `int`. The problem is, his algorithm combines all them into a single int. I'm not sure what the purpose of this is, or how he decided how the final result should be calculated, but this doesn't seem easily reversable (ints back to `String`)

Comment: ...Maybe I should have clarified. Could you put that in the answer itself? Otherwise people will look at the answer, copy/paste, and have no idea how it works because they didn't look at the comments.

Comment: @QPayTaxes Just check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29882034/2398375).. It's a lot less verbose and actually fits the requirements (although this might fit the requirements, it's obviously confusing, and reversing the action would be quite difficult)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the given string in the constructor parameter of `StringBuilder` class and use the [`codePointAt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#codePointAt(int)) method. It returns the ASCII value of character at the index specified.

There are other useful methods also in `StringBuilder` like [`codePointBefore(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#codePointBefore(int)) and [`appendCodePoint(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#appendCodePoint(int)), which allow you to see the codepoint of the character before and append the character with the specified codepoint to the `StringBuilder`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Using `getBytes()`, you can get a `byte[]` containing an number representation of each letter in the `String`:

```
byte[] text = "hello".getBytes();

for(byte b : text) {
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

This gives the same results as:

```
String text = "hello";

for(char c : text.toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println((int) c);
}
```

This is the easiest way I can possibly think of to achieve this goal. To convert it back to String:

```
byte[] byteArray = "hello".getBytes();

String string = new String(byteArray);
```

Comment: This does not give the same results for multibyte characters.

Answer (score 0):

I assume here that the `int` value of each `char` should correspond to the [Unicode code point](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) of that character. If so, then the solution is trivial: you only need to type-cast between the `char` and `int` types. This is because in Java, a `char` is actually an [Integral type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) just like an `int`. The `char` type can hold integer values that represent the code points of 16-bit Unicode characters (`'\u0000'` to `'\uffff'` or `0...65535`).

The solution is to first, convert the `String` into a `char[]` using [`toCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()). Then, simply cast each `char` into an `int` to get the Unicode code point value:

```
int capitalACodePoint = (int)'A';
```

Similarly, cast to `char` to get the value back:

```
char capitalA = (char) 65;
```

A runnable example:

```
String input =  "hello";        
List<Integer> codePoints = new ArrayList<>();

for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
    int codePoint = (int)c;
    codePoints.add(codePoint);
    System.out.println(String.format(
            "char$ %d %s equals %d", 
            codePoints.size(), c, codePoint));
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int codePoint : codePoints) {
    sb.append((char) codePoint);
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

prints out

```
char$ 1 h equals 104
char$ 2 e equals 101
char$ 3 l equals 108
char$ 4 l equals 108
char$ 5 o equals 111
hello
```

This code also works with non-ASCII characters. Changing the input to

```
String input =  "©†¿™";
```

prints out

```
char$ 1 © equals 169
char$ 2 † equals 8224
char$ 3 ¿ equals 191
char$ 4 ™ equals 8482
©†¿™
```

Comment: I'm almost certain that you're getting the *ASCII* codepoints when you cast to `int`.

Comment: It doesn't really matter because for every character that has an ASCII value, the Unicode code point and the ASCII value of that character are the same.

Comment: But if I try to parse a Unicode-only character as ASCII, it won't work the same. It'll give me either an error or an undefined result

Comment: Well, that's simply because [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) only encodes 128 characters, whereas the latest version of Unicode encodes ca 110k characters. I don't get your point, really.

Comment: My point is that, if this only works for ASCII -- which I'm fairly certain it does, but I could be wrong about -- then any of those other ~110k-128 characters won't work with your code, but you're suggesting it will.

Comment: A [`char`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) in Java representents a 16-bit Unicode character. So casting a `char` into an `int` has nothing to do with ASCII. (The cast is actually not even needed but it makes the code perhaps a bit more readable.) I've added a test case using a `String` that has characters with code points larger than 128.

Comment: Well, in that case, my entire premise was wrong. In retrospect, I _probably_ should have consulted Google. Oops.